# JavaScript sorting array with same item

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array. I wanted to sort it such that for the same accountID, I store all the items as an array item. Sample inputs:

```
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWekpN2BfOFcdbS", itemName: "Petrol Charges At Esso"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWekpN2BfOFcdbS", itemName: "Hylo Lubricant Eye Drops 10ml"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWekpN2BfOFcdbS", itemName: "Genteal Gel, Sterile Lubricant Eye Gel, 10g"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWekpN2BfOFcdbS", itemName: "Genteal Gel, Sterile Lubricant Eye Gel, 10g"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWekpN2BfOFcdbS", itemName: "Blink Intensive Tears Protective Eye Drops 0.4mlx20"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWekpN2BfOFcdbS", itemName: "Palmers White And Even Dark Circles Eye Treatment Cream 15ml"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWq445Uao_9sgNn", itemName: "Sensitive Pro-relief With Whitening Toothpaste 110g"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWq445Uao_9sgNn", itemName: "2 In 1 Pure Breath Toothpaste"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWq445Uao_9sgNn", itemName: "Antibackterial Mouthwash 200ml"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWq445Uao_9sgNn", itemName: "Akira 1.7l Jug Kettle Jk1718c"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWq445Uao_9sgNn", itemName: "Duracell Alkaline Batteries Aaa 12s"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWq445Uao_9sgNn", itemName: "Osram Led Star Classic A100 Light Bulb - Frosted Warm White 10.5w/827"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWq445Uao_9sgNn", itemName: "Sharks Fin Soup With Crab Meat And Cordyceps"}],
[{accountID: "-Ks8mWWq445Uao_9sgNn", itemName: "Chilli Fried Rice With Shrimps"}],
```

[image]

Desired outputs to be printed to a text file:

```
['Petrol Charges At Esso', 'Hylo Lubricant Eye Drops 10ml', 'Genteal Gel, Sterile Lubricant Eye Gel, 10g', 'Blink Intensive Tears Protective Eye Drops 0.4mlx20', 'Palmers White And Even Dark Circles Eye Treatment Cream 15ml'],
['Sensitive Pro-relief With Whitening Toothpaste 110g', '2 In 1 Pure Breath Toothpaste', 'Antibackterial Mouthwash 200ml', 'Akira 1.7l Jug Kettle Jk1718c', 'Duracell Alkaline Batteries Aaa 12s', 'Osram Led Star Classic A100 Light Bulb - Frosted Warm White 10.5w/827', 'Sharks Fin Soup With Crab Meat And Cordyceps', 'Chilli Fried Rice With Shrimps'],
```

My code in JavaScript:

```
// for simplicity purpose, I do not post the chunk where I resolve the promise. 
promiseKey.then((arr) => {
console.log(arr);
            var result = arr.reduce(function(items, item) {
                var existing = items.find(function(i) {
                    return i.accountID === item.accountID;
                });

                if (existing) {
                    existing.filteredlist.push(item.itemName);
                } else {
                    items.push(item);
                }
            return items;
            }, []);
            console.log('filtered');
            console.log(result);
});
```

The error that I am getting is Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at the else statement there.

Comment: can you show your array declaration

Comment: @programtreasures You mean 'arr' or 'filteredlist'? If 'arr', the data was previously retrieved from firebase. For simplicity purpose, I just console.log and format the input myself rather than post the whole chunk of retrieval.

Comment: @guest176969 Your input is not **an array**, it's **a bunch of arrays**. Choose one!

Comment: I have updated the question. Check the screenshot :) I might be formatting in the wrong way, I apologize for that!

Comment: The problem is that your `existing.filteredlist` filed is never created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a more simplistic approach using a foreach loop and an object.

```
var items = {};

arr.forEach(function(item) {

    if(!items.hasOwnProperty(item.accountID)) {
        items[item.accountID] = [];
    }

    items[item.accountID].push(item.itemName);
});
```

You can use `Object.keys(items)` to get the keys of each account.

```
Object.keys(items).forEach(function(account) {
    // account is the accountID

    var accountItems = items[account];
});
```

Comment: I am getting accountID of undefined error message :(

Comment: I have tested on my end and it works on my side. The problem must be the underlying promise.

Comment: I managed to print out the data in arr though so I don't think it's related to the promise.

Comment: Try removing the `[0]` from itemArray.

Comment: It works with the version where you put the const items = {}; But then when I put a for loop trying to access 'items' nothing was printed out. It only printed out the sorted array together with its accountID without the for loop

Comment: I edited my post with an example to access items

Comment: Please use the updated version. I made a mistake previously.

Comment: Cool thanks so much!!

Comment: Hey let's say if I got another field called receiptID. Then, I wanted to sort by accountID, followed by receiptID and store the item in the same way. How can I actually achieve this? Just add another if condition in the first forEach will suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to initialize before `filteredlist` use

updated code

```
console.log(arr);
            var result = arr.reduce(function(items, item) {
                var existing = items.find(function(i) {
                    return i.accountID === item.accountID;
                });

                if (existing) {                  
                   existing.filteredlist = [];
                    existing.filteredlist.push(item.itemName);
                } else {
                    items.push(item);
                }
            return items;
            }, []);
            console.log('filtered');
            console.log(result);
```

here is my jsbin demo https://jsbin.com/tepedut/edit?js,console

**EDIT :**

As per your comment you need to sort `arr` with `accountID` property, you can use javascript `arr.sort(function(a, b){});` function to sort the array.

here is updated code

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
   if(a.accountID < b.accountID) return -1;
    if(a.accountID > b.accountID) return 1;
    return 0;
});

console.log(arr);
```

updated js bin https://jsbin.com/tepedut/8/edit?js,console

Comment: Is there anyway to print out the itemName as desired output? Because currently the console.log(result) is printing out with the accountID as well

Comment: check this updated js bin added `item.itemName` to array https://jsbin.com/tepedut/5/edit?js,console

Comment: But if that's the case it just push every single item regardless of the accountID into a single array. Is there any way to separate it such that each accountID printed out as per the desired output?

Comment: do you need to also return accountID  in result ?

Comment: Nope nope, I only need the items sorted by each accountID as per the desired output part

Comment: please check updated answer